# Getting GPS data from Android Phone

Tags: android, gps

i try to get gps data. But gps data return null value. When i looked, following 'location' is return null, so i could not get gps data.
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

My code is following;

```
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager)           mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled)
        {

        }
        else if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) 
        {
                        } 
        else 
        {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {

                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

i wait your help. Thanks

Comment: I found out that sometimes the function getLastKnownLocation() can return null if the user hasn't activated/used the location source for a while. It's better to check like you do. If it's null, then you have to wait for the next location update

Comment: Or set up a requestSingleUpdate or requestLocationUpdates to turn on the GPS yourself.

Comment: If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned. I use GPS_PROVIDER. How can i enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set these in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed like following code, then worked successfully.

```
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    if (locationManager != null) {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }
}
```